# Clash of package versions while installing gfortran on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, gfortran

I am using the command `yum install gcc-fortran` to install gfortran on my Fedora Linux system. However I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Package: gcc-gfortran-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 (base_install-Server)
           Requires: gcc = 4.4.6-3.el6
           Installed: devtoolset-2-gcc-4.8.2-15.1.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-dts2-6)
               gcc = 4.8.2-15.1.el6
           Installed: gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
               gcc = 4.4.7-11.el6
           Available: gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 (base_install-Server)
               gcc = 4.4.6-3.el6
               gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How should I rectify this?

Comment: IIt looks like superuser or unix stackexchage might be a better place to ask. This is not a programming problem (though it does nconcern a programming tool).

Comment: Why do you have installed GCC version 4.8.2 from RedHat Enterprise Linux on your Fedora? And if you want that, why don't you install gfortran from the same source?

Comment: Is it gedora? Why are you using `el6` packages for RHEL6?